# Error in meteor install-sdk android on windows 10

Tags: android, meteor, windows-10, angular-meteor

I got an issue on meteor JS on my windows 10, I have installed android studio and Java 8 JDK. On my meteor project I tried to build an android by typing `meteor install-sdk android`, but I got an error of `This command is not yet available on Windows.` .. Does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 2):

I know this was posted a year ago, but I found a fix recently, just in case anybody gets stuck on this and needs help.

It's from this link: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4155#issuecomment-384105563

But I'll repost the solution with a few extra changes I had to make by myself.

Basically you need to install Android studio and run it to get the Android SDK, install the Java JDK, and install Cordova. After this you can add the android platform to meteor.

Steps:

1. Install Android Studio
2. Run Android Studio once for download, full installation, and accept terms
3. Update npm with `npm i npm`
4. Run `npm install cordova -g` (-g flag for global install)
5. Run `meteor npm i -g write-file-atomic path-is-inside async-some dezalgo`
6. Run `meteor add-platform android`

After doing this, you should be able to run `meteor run android-device` to run on your Android device using a USB cable.

**NOTE:**
If you are connected to a WiFi network while running `meteor run android-device`, you might get an error similar to this:

> Error detecting IP address for mobile app to connect to:
>   Found multiple network interfaces with non-internal IPv4 addresses:
>   '*some IP address*', '*some IP address*'
>   Please specify the address that the mobile app should connect
>   to with --mobile-server.

To fix this, modify the command to:

```
meteor run android-device --mobile-server <ip.of.my.device>
```

**Of course, ensure your PC and Android device are on the same WiFi network.**

Go to **Settings>About Device>Status** to get your current IP Address on your Android device.

The app will now be installed on your phone over the WiFi connection.

(It might take a while though)

Hope this helps.
Cheers.